# Template deduction of std::bind when it comes to temporary class copies

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is the template header of `std::bind`:

```
template< class R, class F, class... Args >
bind( F&& f, Args&&... args );
```

We can bind specific functions depending on what we want to achieve such as `member functions` or normal function.

Although what concerns me is this: if we do something like:

```
auto p = std::bind(&miguel::changex,&m,1);    //miguel is a class and changex is the function
```

We bind it by reference, therefore any changes will definitely affect the original.

If we do it by like this :

```
auto p = std::bind(&miguel::changex,m,1);    //miguel is a class and changex is the function
```

It will be a copy, any changes made won't reflect to the original.

**My question:**

How is `bind( F&& f, Args&&... args );` evaluated for copies when they both take `universal reference`?

Comment: Are they copied internally when creating the wrapper?

Comment: Both make copies. In the first case you are copying a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
auto p = std::bind(&miguel::changex,&m,1);
```

here &m is pass a pointer which point to m to bind, not a reference，so any changes can definitely affect the original.